# How to print a vivid Cyan?

Tags: color, print-design, color-reproduction

Greetings Fellow Designers

I want to print a vivid Cyan for a Business Card. Its hex code is #04f1d7. It was sent by my client to me and it was designed in RGB. Now the client is stuck on this option to print, while after converting to CMYK it becomes dull.

But I am getting as image below. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[image]

[There was already a question like this on this site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/can-you-convert-a-neon-rgb-color-to-cmyk-for-printing) but I am looking to catch a straw.

Comment: The link you provided already answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer—You can't.

Forget about the RGB color, use a spot color or pick a new CMYK color, the RGB color you have doesn't exist in a CMYK color space. You should always be designing anything destined for print in CMYK.

Related: [Why do professional print houses use gamut-limiting CMYK?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61294/why-do-professional-print-houses-use-gamut-limiting-cmyk/62677#62677)

Comment: Thank you very much for response, I got it sorted, one of my friend told me that fluorescent colors will be helpful in this regards. Thanks again..